# UsageStatsManager.getAppStandbyBucket() : Unresolved method

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-10.0

I'm trying to access the standby bucket that my app is currently in by calling `UsageStatsManager.getAppStandbyBucket()` in my activity, but the `getAppStandbyBucket()` method is unresolved. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event) say that the method is public. I've ensured that my compilesdk and targetsdk are both set to 28. My buildtools are also up to date.

Edit:
This is not duplicate. I needed to access the Application to be able to get the UsageStatsManager - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that worked for me. This is the code you'll need if you're outside of an activity.

```
private fun getStandByBucketIfAvailable(): Int {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
        getStandByBucket()
    } else {
        0
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private fun getStandByBucket(): Int {
    val usageStatsManager = application.getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
    return usageStatsManager.appStandbyBucket
}
```

If you are in an activity all you'll need is this

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
            val usageStatsManager = getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
            Log.d(TAG, "getAppStandbyBucket():" + usageStatsManager.appStandbyBucket)
}
```